# Ruby install ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am installing Ruby on a free test hosting. when i run the configure.

```
provespr [Mon Jun 27 16:42]#./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
```

But it show that error:

```
./configure: line 469: expr: command not found
./configure.lineno: line 469: expr: command not found
```

I get the tar.gz file from ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby. And always get that error.

Comment: Are you trying to build Ruby? If that's the case you are probably missing development dependencies. But is there a reason to do that in the first place? Why not installing ruby from a package manager?

Comment: thanks Nic for your response. I am  trying install Ruby ,via hosting web, connecting via SHH(cshell). I don't have package manager.

Comment: Windows 7. Iam working via putty.

Comment: I mean your hosted OS where you're trying to install Ruby.

Comment: Thansk @Nic Nilov. I' am working on a terminal and when i write set: it put me :
MACHTYPE=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
and OSTYPE=linux-gnu.                                                                      Other information apt-get,yum and other commands soens not working.

Comment: Run `uname -a` in your terminal and see if there is more info.

Comment: i don't have commands like "uname"  and other like "make"

Comment: Without knowing your environment it can be quite hard to figure out what's going on, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Nicido Nilov no problem. If i found something i'd  post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install it by rvm - this way you can easily switch between versions and implementations

https://rvm.io

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: Thanks @lumos0815 for your response Iam trying on it. But it put me gpg command not found /curl command not found.Then i was trying to install gpg but i don't have bzip2 i trying to instal bzip2. But when i was trying to "./configure" it put an error command not found--> it is a Take command  I saw a on configrue file. At the end i went to ruby tar.gz. I execute ./configure. Showed me error I read the line 469 of the file configure i comment those lines (argument with sed command). I run configure again then i run make and with make put me command not found again. I m searching

Comment: as you don't know which linux distribution you are using please try the following commands     "dmesg | head"    and    "cat /proc/version"   and "cat /etc/issue" and post the output here

Comment: Thanks lumos0815 Debian GNU/Linux 7  it works with cat /etc/issue.

Comment: so you should be able to work with apt-get - do you have a root account on this server? try to run "apt-get update" and "apt-get install gnupg curl" as root

Comment: Sorry and don't put it i am tryying intall apt.get thanks to this people: http://apst.stsci.edu/apt/external/downloads/installers/install.html . I dont have apt-get command. I am tryingto install java too beacause this apt need java. Thanks @lumos0815

Comment: this apt you mention above is not the package installer for debian. do you really have a server where you are allowed to install stuff or is this just some kind of webspace?

Comment: You are right i ask to the hosting and they not allow to install modules and something else. Thansk for all.